# Pytorch List object has no attribute ‘to’

Tags: pytorch, torch, transfer-learning, torchvision, mscoco

I am new to Pytorch. I am using a pre-trained model (RESNET-50). And i am trying to train this model on MS-COCO dataset using cocoapi.

I have loaded my dataset images and annotations in train loader.

```
for images,labels in train_loader:
    print(type(images))
    print(type(labels))
    print(images.size())
    print(images.dim())
    steps+=1
    images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

i got the following output:

class 'torch.Tensor'

class 'list'

torch.Size([64, 3, 224, 224])

4

And i got this Error: I think it is because labels is not a Tensor?

[image: Error output image]

Answer (score 0):

In your DataLoader you can do something like:

```
labels = torch.as_tensor([lbl for lbl in labels])
```

or if your DataLoader returns a list of torch tensors, you can send them to the device:

```
labels = [lbl.to(device) for lbl in labels]
```